# IIS express how to use custom configuration

Tags: visual-studio, configuration, web-config, iis-express

I would like to use different configuration with my IIS express, how I can run solution from visual studio in this case.
IIS express is using configs files not from my build configuration.

Comment: IIS Express uses the web.config from your project, but a per user global applicationHost.config file by default. Only in VS 2015 it switches to a per solution approach.